# How can I change the weather?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

It's Sunny out, and that seems to be helping the Pokemon I am currently trying to beat.

How can I change the weather so that they don't have this advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: for this question I am ignoring the ORAS weathers.

There are four weather conditions in Pokémon, which I will refer to by the move used to summon them:

- Rain Dance
- Sunny Day
- Sandstorm
- Hail

All four moves can be taught by TM, with some Pokémon learning them naturally by level up. All four are purchased at the Royal Avenue Poké Mart, and will last 5 turns after use. All weather effects can override each other.

**Rain Dance** boosts the power of Water-type moves by 50%, while reducing the power of Fire-type moves by 50%. During Rain Dance, Thunder and Hurricane always hit their target, Solar Beam has its Base Power reduced to 60, and Synthesis, Morning Sun, and Moonlight only recover 25% of the user's max HP.

**Sunny Day** boosts the power of Fire-type moves by 50%, while reducing the power of Water-type moves by 50%. During Sunny Day, Thunder and Hurricane have their accuracy lowered to 50, Growth boosts Attack and Special Attack by 2 stages, Solar Beam and Solar Blade require no charge turn, and Synthesis, Morning Sun, and Moonlight recover 66% of the user's max HP.

**Sandstorm** deals damage at the end of each turn to every non-Rock- , Ground-, or Steel-type Pokémon, and boosts the Special Defense of Rock-type Pokémon by 50%. During a Sandstorm, Solar Beam has its Base Power reduced to 60, and Synthesis, Morning Sun, and Moonlight only recover 25% of the user's max HP.

**Hail** deals damage at the end of each turn to every non-Ice-type Pokémon. During Hail, Blizzard always hits its target, Solar Beam has its Base Power reduced to 60, and Synthesis, Morning Sun, and Moonlight only recover 25% of the user's max HP.

Many Abilities are activated during one of the four weather conditions.

Additionally, the Abilities Drizzle, Drought, Sand Stream, and Snow Warning will respectively trigger the effects of Rain Dance, Sunny Day, Sandstorm, and Hail when a Pokémon with the Ability is switched in.